# Erlang : How to reuse strategy represented in the form of gen_fsm?

Tags: erlang

I am implementing robo-soccer which uses **gen_fsm** to represent **strategy** of each robot.
I have developed the strategy for attacker. Now, I want to use the same strategy for running multiple attackers, say 5 attackers. For this purpose, I have to copy the same gen_fsm code(200 lines) at 5 different modules resulting in total 1000 lines of code.
Is there a way to write a gen_fsm and **reuse** it in multiple modules? 
A sample code snippet is

```
-module(planner).
-behaviour(gen_fsm).
 start() -> 
    start_link().
start_link() ->
    gen_fsm:start_link({local, ?SERVER}, ?MODULE, [], []).

init([]) ->
    {ok, state1, ets:new(test,[public])}.

state1({test},State) ->
    case ets:lookup(State,ball) of
[] ->
    action!{turn,80}, 
    {next_state,state1,State};
Data ->
  % some code % %,
  {next_state,state2,State}
end;

state2({test},State) ->

 % --- some code ---%
```

Comment: As the other answers have implied, but not explicitly stated, there is no limit to how many processes you can have which run the same code. So if in your case you want 5 players then it is probably easiest to have 5 processes running the same fsm logic code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably start the `gen_fsm` process without a globally registered name. Try:

```
start_link() ->
    gen_fsm:start_link(?MODULE, [], []).
```

Remember to keep track of your processes using the process id returned from `gen_fsm:start_link/3`.

Comment: Very important to keep track of the Pid returned by `spawn_link`, +1.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just spawn 5 processes, 1 for each attacker, that runs the same code?